# can not connect to mysql using the password

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Hi i have just created a mysql user sukant1 and password also sukant1 but i am not able to connect it .please see the below

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'sukant1'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'sukant1';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> exit
Bye


[sukanth@SWD11 ~]$ mysql -u sukant1 -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'sukant1'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: What password did you enter ?

Comment: @NoobUnChained sukant1, the same one when i created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably is connecting through socket. Well, just try

```
$ mysql -u sukant1 -p
```

And when the shell asks you about the password, DON'T TYPE ANY PASSWORD and then you should be in.

However, I'd recommend to you to create your users using the code below:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'MY_USER'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MY_PASS';
```

[EDIT]

What is happening is the fact you have multiple matches in your table mysql.user for the one you are trying to connect with. You can read more about mysql access [control here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/connection-access.html).

To sort your issue out for now, log in your database with other use and type:

```
SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user order by user;
```

You might be able to see something like that:

```
+------------------+-------------+
| user             | host        |
+------------------+-------------+
|                  | localhost   |
| sukant1          | %           |
| sukant1          | localhost   |
| root             | localhost   |
+------------------+-------------+
```

Now, delete the users:

```
delete from mysql.user where user = '' and host = 'localhost';
delete from mysql.user where user = 'sukant1' and host = 'localhost';
```

Now you should be able to acess the database as you want. But, then again, it is not the best way to do it. Ready the link I sent to you and use more specific host names e.g. localhost.

Comment: see in my system only mysql is installed and other system does not have mysql.so i am using '%' instead of localhost.hope you have understood my requirement

Comment: check the answer again pls.

Comment: thanks for your beautiful answer but i have already solved it. thanks again for giving your valuable time for my problem

Comment: @javaL: Were not the multiple sukant1 entries your problem?

Comment: @Costis Aivalis  when i was trying to connect in mysql admin then there was problem but when i tried to connect using java,the problem is solved.Moreover i want only jdbc to connect to mysql and operation using jdbc

Answer (score 0):

try to access mysql as root....sometimes mysql access is not given to all users.

```
su root

[root@SWD11 ~]$ mysql -u sukant1 -p
```

Comment: still getting error
[sukanth@SWD11 ~]$ su root
Password: 
[root@SWD11 sukanth]# mysql -u sukant1 -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'sukant1'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
[root@SWD11 sukanth]#

Answer (score 0):

[Reset your root password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/resetting-permissions.html), though it is not advisable.

Comment: thanks for your answer see i created another user test and password also test and this time also this is not working. i think this is not the way to connect to mysql else it would not give error in all users.your reply is highly needed